# Data Corruption when writing from PLC to PC into SQL Table

Tags: sql, insert, communication, plc

I've connected my PLC to a computer over Ethernet. If the machine is testing I'm writing the test data into an SQL table.

This works well, but there is sometimes some data corruption.

This data corruption is in 99% of the case small deviance between the PLC and PC value, for instance, plc value is 10 the PC value will be 9,999999. In the other  1% value with a 1.33 +47 will be written into the SQL table.

What I want is to be absolutely sure the written value is also the measurement value.

What I have tried:
- Changing write interval from 100ms to 1sec
- Disabled all other communication

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Divide and conquer.  Isolate the problem.  Look at the actual SQL insert statement. 
 Do you have a log of the actual SQL statement that is inserting the record (vs. just a query of the row w/bad data).  It could be some of your PLC data contains SQL type grammar as part of the data (e.g. double quotes, or missing quotes, etc.), causing the SQL command handler to mess up (think SQL injection type scenarios).

Comment: What protocol are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure that on the PLC side the address or parts of the address do not have a different use temporarily in the PLC cycle?

If yes, it is possible that at the time of reading the value, e.g. 32Bit value is only partially available in one of 2 16Bit registers, e.g. DW in a DB. This results in unusual numbers when reading and interpreting in float. A hint for this can be the interpretation of 10 as 9.99999 - but it does not have to be. It would be important to know which value type in which variable type on which type of PLC should be read with which protocol.